# .net core app is not starting after deployment from vscode "Azure App Services" extension. (from macOS)

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-webapps

I deploy my .net core app to azure web app from a vscode for Mac. I use Azure App Service extension for vscode. I check with Kudu that all files was succesfuly uploaded to the server but when im trying to open my site in browser it says that "site is under construction". When im doing that from my windows pc at work from visual studio everything is working without exposing me to anything. It's just deployed everything when I push the button and website is updated and working. What happens when im pressing that button? How I can manually start .net core app on my server? Is there a way to configure "Azure App Service" extension to do it all automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is to:

1. Change the appService.deploySubpath of the vs code extension "Azure App Service" to "/publish"
   [VS Code Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlO63.png)
2. Run dotnet release build
   dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
3. Right click the publish folder and "Deploy to Web App"